# Why does regex ^(?:a+)+$ causes catastrophic backtracking?

Tags: regex, algorithm

I'm learning both compiler principles(whose regex can always do task in `O(n)`) and general regular expressions. I notice that some regex may have catastrophic backtracking, which seems to be in conflict with theory.

Theoretically, `^(?:a+)+$` can be turned into an NFA like:

[image: NFA]

And by algorithm, it can be turned into a DFA that has exact states as `a+`. But in real life, it will cause catastrophic backtracking for e.g. `aaaaaab`. Why cannot the regex be compiled into an efficient DFA? Or generally, a regex composed of `|,*,+,(?:)` should be equivalent to some non-backtracking DFA, which is at most `O(n^2)` if we start from every possible character and fail every time, but why can it be like exponential complexity? Are there any differences between regex in compiler principle and general regex used in the program?

Comment: It *could* be compiled into a DFA, but compilation is costly. And for many regular expression, the DFA becomes prohibitively large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are DFA regex engines and there are backtracking regex engines. Generally speaking, a language or library either decides that it wants features that can only be supported with a backtracking engine (like backreferences or arbitrary lookaround), in which case it compiles to that sort of structure — or it decides that it can do without such features and compiles to a DFA.

Although it would be possible to choose the matching strategy on a pattern-by-pattern basis, or to apply both strategies (using a DFA to weed out definite non-matches before feeding the remainder to a backtracking engine), for reasons of complexity this is pretty much never done.

So, a DFA engine can't "catastrophically backtrack" on your pattern. A backtracking one might or might not. It's completely possible for it to analyze the pattern and recognize that `^(?:a+)+$` can only match if `a$` can, and fail the match early, but that's a game of halting problem whack-a-mole: how many cases do you cover, how much code do you write, and how much work do you spend pre-processing in order to *maybe* short-circuit a brute-force match?

Comment: I think TCL's regex engine is one of the few notable examples of an actual hybrid implementation. It seems like most implementations these days just go for a full backtracking approach.

Comment: Google's re2 library, and go's regexp package are (not entirely different because they're both originally written by Russ Cox) examples of regular expression libraries that don't do backtracking.

Comment: This problem can be solved in a backtracking engine with checks to keep from wasting time redoing the same work. You don't even need to perform the checks very often. Perl does that.